# Django manage.py runserver command freezing on OSX

Tags: python, django, pycharm

I have a few different systems that I use for development of a Django project. The main being Linux, then Windows, and then Mac...all systems implement development using Pycharm

Up until about a week ago I was able to develop my Django project on Mac just fine, I could run the server and check updates as usual, however, for some reason I cannot seem to figure out, the terminal just freezes for about **5 minutes** when I run:

```
python3 manage.py runserver 8000
```

The server still starts after that **5 minutes** but the startup time is quite literally awful, and I do not know what to look at to figure out where the issue is.

I have not changed my code between work and home, just pulled directly from Git and I have the same issues. On my Windows System at home the Django app also runs within a few seconds of starting the server, as does the Linux system at work, so it seems to be only happening on OSX.

Again, I am using Pycharm, but even if I manually enter the project directory and run the server, the startup time is slow

Has anybody run into issues like this, or where can I look to try and find the cause of the error?

Comment: What is the python version you are using in OSX? If its old, can you update it and try to run the server again?

Comment: 3.7 on OSX, the same as Windows. I am using 3.6 on Linux

Comment: Not sure why you are be facing this. I had similar issue with old python version(2.6 maybe, i don't remeber) which came built in with os. But updating resolved that.

Comment: Are there any debug logs (somewhere) showing what is happening when the command is run? Maybe I can track it down that way....all else fails I can either reinstall Python3.7 and/or (worst case) reset the computer back to factory and reset the system (but I really don't want to need to do this)

Comment: Not sure about that. Maybe you can override the runserver command using custom management command, then put a debugger on the command to see where it goes(its another extreme suggestion). Try reinstalling python with brew first. if it does not work, then try with my suggestion :)

Comment: I ran through the reinstallation of python3.7 and the error/lag persisted. I didn't want to waste more time in the event it was needed so I simply did a fresh install and set everything back up. I am now running normally and the project runs as expected. This is an odd situation though, everything was fine until that latest Mojave update on OSX...maybe that fiddled somehow with the python installation...either way I did use brew (as usual) and I am good now after an annoying reset, thanks for the input, at least I know this has happened to someone else at some point!